# Exception handling in LocalTransaction.commit()

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jca

We try to write a JCA adapter that should support local transactions.
We would like to use last agent optimization to put our connector in the same transaction with an XADataSource.

According to the spec, `LocalTransactions.commit` should throw `LocalTransactionException` to indicate an error during commit, and it should result in rollbacking the XA transaction.
However, this does not happen. We just see some stack traces in server.log, and the transaction remains in prepared state (and hangs there).
We debugged the call, and glassfish really executes last agent optimization, but `ConnectorXAResource.commit` (which calls it), translates the `LocalTransactionException` into an exception that doesn't result in rollback.

Any suggestion to solve this?